# How to fix common 500 internal server error when use POST method on NEXTJS

Tags: mongodb, next.js, oauth, prisma

When I fill the user register data such as username, password and email address and then I click continuce button, I got the 500 internal server error. I'm really stuck in the **POST **method.

[FORM UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRjCj.png)

I used NextJS latest version app features. I setup correctly prisma schema file and env variables. But I got the 500 internal error. Alright, so I open debugger tool and I seen that error on my file RegisterModal.tsx. I tried another solution on my project but I facing the 500 error. If you can please check my code and what should be wrong in my project. I have been opened network tabs it show me 500 internal server error. What should I do that?

[This is my project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1JBH.png)

**RegisterModal.tsx**

```
// RegisterModal.jsx

"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { AiFillGithub } from "react-icons/ai";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";
import Button from "../Button";
import {
  FieldValues,
  SubmitHandler,
  useForm,
} from "react-hook-form";
import useRegisterModal from "@/app/hooks/useRegisterModal";
import Heading from "@/app/components/Heading";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import Input from "../inputs/Input";

const RegisterModal = () => {
  const registerModal = useRegisterModal();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FieldValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = (data) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .post("/api/register", data)
      .then(() => {
        registerModal.onClose();
        toast.success("Registration successful!");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error(err.response.data.message || "An error occurred");
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  const bodyContent = (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      <Heading title="Welcome to Airbnb" subTitle="Create an account for free" />
      <Input
        id="email"
        label="Email"
        disabled={isLoading}
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
        required
      />
      <Input
        id="name"
        label="Name"
        disabled={isLoading}
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
        required
      />
      <Input
        id="password"
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        disabled={isLoading}
        register={register}
        errors={errors}
        required
      />
    </div>
  );

  const footerContent = (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 mt-3">
      <hr />
      <Button
        outline
        label="Register with Google"
        icon={FcGoogle}
        onClick={() => {}}
      />
      <Button
        outline
        label="Register with Github"
        icon={AiFillGithub}
        onClick={() => {}}
      />
      <div className="text-natural-500 text-center mt-4 font-light">
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center gap-2">
          <div>Already have an account?</div>
          <div
            onClick={registerModal.onClose}
            className="text-natural-800 cursor-pointer hover:underline"
          >
            Login
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <Modal
      disabled={isLoading}
      isOpen={registerModal.isOpen}
      title="Register"
      actionLabel="Continue"
      onClose={registerModal.onClose}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      body={bodyContent}
      footer={footerContent}
    />
  );
};

export default RegisterModal;
```

**

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts**

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter"

import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb"

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        });

        if (!user || !user?.hashedPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }

        return user;
      }
    })
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/',
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

**

libs/prismadb.ts**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined
}

const client = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient()
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prisma = client

export default client
```

**

api/register/route.ts**

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";

export async function POST(
  request: Request, 
) {
  const body = await request.json();
  const { 
    email,
    name,
    password,
   } = body;

   const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

   const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email,
      name,
      hashedPassword,
    }
  });

  return NextResponse.json(user);
}
```

I spend 4 to 5 hours of time to fix that errors. But in this time, I got the still errors. Please help me the hell.

Comment: We can't guess what the error is. Figure out how to log the actual error in Next.js, possibly https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/error-handling, and start from there.